# WebORB and "Code Generation Failed" message

Tags: .net, weborb

I'm trying to get an installation of webOrb 3.6.0.3 working, but am stuck getting the model to "build".

I've connected to the database server, with the proper credentials. WebOrb asks
me which specific DB to connect to, and displays the list for me to choose from,
so I know that part is working. In the databases list, I can drill into my DB,
and into my tables to see the columns.

Then I drag a table over into the main model window.  Then, if I select the green checkbox, it tells me "Data model validated, no errors found". So then I click on the gears icon, to build the simple model, and I get this sequence....

```
. . Trying connect to WebORB using RTMP, attempt 1
. . RTMP connection successfully established
. . Starting code generation for model "asdf"
. . Code generation failed.
```

Thats it...I can't see anything else that I'm missing. I've done everything
exactly as the Developer Den video lays out.

Can anyone provide a suggestion or some additional help? I'm quite stuck!

Thanks.

Comment: I checked with the developers of the software, and all I could get from them that its a configuration error.  Unfortunately, its a default, vanilla install!  I'm not the slightest bit certain of what else I can do.  Seems, at this point, to be more of a bug in the installer, than in anything I've done

Comment: The results of my latest installation: 

I created a new virtual machine, installed MS Server 2003, SQL2000, and weborb on it.

From this new install I was not only able to generate the full data model of NorthWind, but I was also able to generate a model for the original VM's real data.

However, going back to the original VM, I was unable to generate either the local 'real' schema, or the new VM's Northwind.

To me, this is highly suggestive of a configuration problem with weborb itself, as opposed to a data/schema error .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a partial solution to this difficulty.  With the assistance of weborb's technical support, we discovered an error in the log file which suggested a permission setting mismatch on C:\Windows\Temp\ .

```
[Thread-7] WEBORB EXCEPTION:1/26/2010 10:16:07 AM:System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\kpfrtmwd.0.cs' could not be found
error CS2008: No inputs specified
```

I had tried adding "full" permissions to "Network System" and to "ASP.NET", according to the WebORB documentation, but neither of those solved the problem.

As a partial solution, we found that by adding the "Everyone" user, and giving it "Full" permissions, I was finally able to compile the code.

It remains yet to be seen which user/group needs to be setup properly for this to work without giving Everyone Full permissions.